# Why is "if isna vlookup" quicker than "countif"?

Tags: excel, performance, excel-formula

I have been trying to find if any data persists across two identical reports, but from two different months.

If the ID of a row exists in the next month, then I call it existing. I can see what has come in new and what is carried forward. All good.

The only way I could think to do this was use

```
=COUNTIF("column of next month IDs","this months ID")
```

do this all the way down, then just sum it. This is however immensely slow and locks up Excel, as it can be run between 60k and 100k rows.

A colleague recommended that instead I use

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP("this months ID","column of next months ID",1,false)),0,1)
```

and sum that instead. Now it still takes a while, but is noticeably quicker. Why is this? It seems more steps and calculation.

Comment: How much faster is it?

Comment: See [Is there a faster COUNTIF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972016/is-there-a-faster-countif/29983885#29983885).

Comment: The `VLOOKUP` can be faster as it only searches the first accordance of "this months ID" in "column of next months ID". `COUNTIF` must count *all* occurrences of "this months ID" in "column of next months ID". So it ever must loop over the whole "column of next months ID".

Comment: Got you, VLOOKUP finds it and stops, as where COUNTIF has to go all the way through as should be used if you expect to see it more than once.

Comment: Maybe I got that wrong, but wouldn't `MATCH` be even faster? Like `=IF(ISNA(MATCH("this months ID","column of next months ID",0)),0,1)`

Comment: Or better `=ISNUMBER(MATCH("this months ID","column of next months ID",0))*1`