# Excel – return number of unique values in ascending order, optimized for 100,000+ cases

Tags: vba, excel

In reference to the excel screen capture below, I’m looking for an optimized formula or VBA solution to do a simple count of the ID values in column A, returning the results in ascending order in column B (this is the desired results). In the example below, there are two '1's in A2 and A3, which would return a '1' and '2' in column B. There are six '2's next in column A, which would return values 1 through 6 in column B, etc. 
I have a formula solution that works fine with cases **< 20,000** but reaches critical error with datasets **>100,000** (I haven’t tried anything between). In B2, the following formula has been used:

`=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)`

I’m having trouble finding a solution that doesn’t kick back errors and will complete **~100,000** cases quickly. My current solution runs for hours before kicking back a memory error. Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any VBA code you are working with?

Comment: Did you tried using pivot table?

Comment: I do not at the moment. My limited talents lie with formulas, unfortunately. I can run and tweak VBA but can't really build from scratch. I generally stay away from pivot tables given the form of my dataset.

Comment: countif() is about as optimized as you can get.  You will need to do this in vba.

Comment: [Is there a faster CountIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972016/is-there-a-faster-countif/29983885?s=1|109.4713#29983885)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Enter in cell `B2`: `1`
2. Enter in cell `B3`: `=IF(A3=A2,B2+1,1)`
3. Drag formula down

Comment: one note with this, It works as long as the id's are sorted.  And since that is what the OP has shown `+1`.

Comment: Well hot damn, that works like a charm! Thank you. FYI, Just ran it on 1.1 million rows and it completes in a few seconds. You saved my day @JohnyL

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve the desired output is as below...

In B2

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)
```

and then copy it down.