# Redundancy in logic for excel VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Please see the image attached -

[image]

My requirement is -

- "If `status null` and `Ref No. not unique` then

> check value2. If value2 not present, check value1 and take average

Example: For ref number = 1, calculated value is (50+10)/2 = 30  "

- "if `status is selected` or `Ref no is unique` then

> copy from value2, if not present then copy from value1

Example: For Ref No 3, value is 100 and for Ref No 4, value is 20

- Total value= 100+30+20 = 150

My attempt

```
For I = 2 To lrow 'sheets all have headers that are 2 rows

        'unique
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("A" & fRow, "A" & lrow), ws.Range("A" & I)) = 1 Then
                If (ws.Range("AW" & I) <> "") Then 'AW has value2
                    calc = calc + ws.Range("AW" & I).Value
                Else: calc = calc + ws.Range("AV" & I).Value 'AV has value1
                End If
        'not unique
            Else
                'selected
                If ws.Range("AY" & I) = "Selected" Then 'AY has status (Selected/Null)
                    If (ws.Range("AW" & I) <> "") Then
                        calc = calc + ws.Range("AW" & I).Value
                    Else: calc = calc + ws.Range("AV" & I).Value
                    End If
                'not selected
                Else
                    If (ws.Range("AW" & I) <> "") Then
                        calc1 = calc1 + ws.Range("AW" & I).Value
                    Else: calc1 = calc1 + ws.Range("AV" & I).Value
                    End If
                    calc1 = calc1/Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("A" & fRow, "A" & lrow), ws.Range("A" & I))
                End If
            End If
```

My problem is -

- Getting the Ref No 3 twice in my logic.
- Not able to calculate the correct average.

How can I get the correct output? Thanks.

Comment: So you ignore row 5?

Comment: Why is the value for Ref4 20? It's unique so shouldn't it be 40?

Comment: Hi. Yes we ignore Row 5 because in Row 4 the value of Ref 3 is selected. And for Ref4, we first have to check value2. If it is not present then we have to check value1.

Comment: match is much [faster than countif[](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972016/is-there-a-faster-countif)]

Comment: Thank you for that @Jeepad. Can you also help me improve my attempt to get the correct output?

Comment: Your response contradicts your question.

Comment: You're right @SJR. Thank you. I have edited my question

Comment: OK. Is the only output you want the 150 or do you need the constituent totals also?

Comment: The only output I want is 150.

Comment: @SJR Could you kindly help me out?

Comment: Yes, I will take a look, but need to give it a bit of thought. In reality do you have a lot of data?

Comment: No I won't have more that 20 rows, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using a SQL statement against the worksheet

If I understand your requirements, they are as follows:

- For each `Ref no`, you want
- the average of

  - `value2` if it exists, otherwise `value1`
- where the `status` is `selected`, or

  - there is no `status = selected` for this `Ref no`

I would open an ADODB Recordset against the data, with the following SQL:

```
SELECT [Ref no], Avg(Iif(value2 IS NOT NULL, value2, value1)) AS Result
FROM Sheet1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Ref No]
    FROM Sheet1
    WHERE status = "selected"
) t1 ON Sheet1.[Ref no] = t1.[Ref no]
WHERE Sheet1.status="selected" OR t1.[Ref no] IS NULL
GROUP BY [Ref no]
```

---

#### Using nested `Scripting.Dictionary`

If SQL is not your thing, then you could something like the following:

```
'Define names for the columns; much easier to read row(RefNo) then arr(0)
Const refNo = 1
Const status = 3
Const value1 = 5
Const value2 = 6

'For each RefNo, we have to store 3 pieces of information:
'   whether any of the rows are selected
'   the sum of the values
'   the count of the values
Dim aggregates As New Scripting.Dictionary

Dim arr() As Variant
arr = Sheet1.UsedRange.Value

Dim maxRow As Long
maxRow = UBound(arr, 1)

Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To maxRow 'exclude the column headers in the first row
    Dim row() As Variant
    row = GetRow(arr, i)

    'Get the current value of the row
    Dim currentValue As Integer
    currentValue = row(value1)
    If row(value2) <> Empty Then currentValue = row(value2)

    'Ensures the dictionary always has a record corresponding to the RefNo
    If Not aggregates.Exists(row(refNo)) Then Set aggregates(row(refNo)) = InitDictionary

    Dim hasPreviousSelected As Boolean
    hasPreviousSelected = aggregates(row(refNo))("selected")

    If row(status) = "selected" Then
        If Not hasPreviousSelected Then
            'throw away any previous sum and count; they are from unselected rows
            Set aggregates(row(refNo)) = InitDictionary(True)
        End If
    End If

    'only include currently seleced refNos, or refNos which weren't previously selected,
    If row(status) = "selected" Or Not hasPreviousSelected Then
        aggregates(row(refNo))("sum") = aggregates(row(refNo))("sum") + currentValue
        aggregates(row(refNo))("count") = aggregates(row(refNo))("count") + 1
    End If
Next

Dim key As Variant
For Each key In aggregates
    Debug.Print key, aggregates(key)("sum") / aggregates(key)("count")
Next
```

with the following two helper functions:

```
Function GetRow(arr() As Variant, rowIndex As Long) As Variant()
    Dim ret() As Variant
    Dim lowerbound As Long, upperbound As Long
    lowerbound = LBound(arr, 2)
    upperbound = UBound(arr, 2)
    ReDim ret(1 To UBound(arr, 2))
    Dim i As Long
    For i = lowerbound To upperbound
        ret(i) = arr(rowIndex, i)
    Next
    GetRow = ret
End Function

Function InitDictionary(Optional selected As Boolean = False) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set InitDictionary = New Scripting.Dictionary
    InitDictionary.Add "selected", selected
    InitDictionary.Add "sum", 0
    InitDictionary.Add "count", 0
End Function
```

---

#### Explanation of SQL

- For each `Ref no`, you want

Group the records by `Ref no`, using the `GROUP BY` clause

- the average of

We'll return both the `Ref no` and the `average` -- `SELECT [Ref no], Avg(...)`

- `value2` if it exists, otherwise `value1`

`Iif(value2 IS NOT NULL, value2, value1)`

- where the `status` is `selected`, or

`WHERE Sheet1.status="selected" OR`

- there is no `status = selected` for this `Ref no`

We get a list of (unique -- `DISTINCT`) `Ref no`s that have `status = "selected"`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Ref No]
FROM Sheet1
WHERE status = "selected"
```

and give it a name (`AS t1`) so we can refer to it separately from the main list (`Sheet1`)

Then we connect, or join (`JOIN`) that sublist to the main list, where the [Ref no] is the same in both (`ON Sheet1.[Ref no] = t1.[Ref no]`).

A simple `JOIN` is an `INNER JOIN`, where the records on both sides of the connection have to match. What we want in this case, is the records on the main list which **do not** match the records in the sublist. In order to see such records, we can use a `LEFT JOIN`, which displays all the records on the left side, and only those records on the right side that match.

We can then filter out the records that do match, using `OR t1.[Ref no] IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a more concise way, but I think this does what you want. It is based on your example, so data in A1:F6 so will need amending.

```
Sub x()

Dim v2() As Variant, v1, i As Long, n As Long, d As Double

v1 = Sheet1.Range("A1:F6").Value
ReDim v2(1 To UBound(v1, 1), 1 To 5) 'ref/count/null/value null/value selected

With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 2 To UBound(v1, 1)
        If Not .Exists(v1(i, 1)) Then
            n = n + 1
            v2(n, 1) = v1(i, 1)
            v2(n, 2) = v2(n, 2) + 1
            If v1(i, 3) = "" Then
                v2(n, 3) = v2(n, 3) + 1
                v2(n, 4) = IIf(v1(i, 6) = "", v1(i, 5), v1(i, 6))
            ElseIf v1(i, 3) = "selected" Then
                v2(n, 5) = IIf(v1(i, 6) = "", v1(i, 5), v1(i, 6))
            End If
            .Add v1(i, 1), n
        ElseIf .Exists(v1(i, 1)) Then
            v2(.Item(v1(i, 1)), 2) = v2(.Item(v1(i, 1)), 2) + 1
            If v1(i, 3) = "" Then
                v2(.Item(v1(i, 1)), 3) = v2(.Item(v1(i, 1)), 3) + 1
                If v1(i, 6) = "" Then
                    v2(.Item(v1(i, 1)), 4) = v2(.Item(v1(i, 1)), 4) + v1(i, 5)
                Else
                    v2(.Item(v1(i, 1)), 4) = v2(.Item(v1(i, 1)), 4) + v1(i, 6)
                End If
            Else
                If v1(i, 6) = "" Then
                    v2(.Item(v1(i, 1)), 5) = v2(.Item(v1(i, 1)), 5) + v1(i, 5)
                Else
                    v2(.Item(v1(i, 1)), 5) = v2(.Item(v1(i, 1)), 5) + v1(i, 6)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With

For i = LBound(v2, 1) To UBound(v2, 1)
    If v2(i, 2) > 1 And v2(i, 3) = v2(i, 2) Then
        d = d + v2(i, 4) / v2(i, 2)
    End If
    If v2(i, 2) > 1 And v2(i, 3) < v2(i, 2) Then
        d = d + v2(i, 5) / (v2(i, 2) - v2(i, 3))
    End If
    If v2(i, 2) = 1 And v2(i, 3) = v2(i, 2) Then
        d = d + v2(i, 4) / v2(i, 2)
    End If
Next i

MsgBox "Total = " & d

End Sub
```

Comment: Hope you're doing well. You asked me if I needed constituent totals as well. At the time I said no. But I think in the future I might need the constituent total as well. Could you kindly tell me how to capture that too? Thanks.

Comment: @PriyankaDembla What do you mean by _constituent totals_?

Comment: If you would kindly look at my question, 100, 20 and 30 are my constituent totals. Thank you

Comment: @PriyankaDembla I should have been more precise: _What steps are needed to figure out the constituent totals?_ Considering that `20` appears twice in the data you have posted, providing 3 arbitrary numbers isn't very helpful when trying to figure out the algorithm for getting constituent totals.

Comment: @ZevSpitz: Please read my requirement in the question. Those 3 numbers are not arbitrary. They have come after deriving a logic. And the answer by SJR covers most of the logic.