# seeing if one excel sheet has a term in it

Tags: excel

I'm Trying to figure out if a term listed in a sheet is also listed in another. All of the other examples I could find only refer to an exact term listed not a2 for example. I'm incorrectly always getting false returned. below is an example

=IF('sheet1'!A:A=sheet2 !A23,"TRUE","FALSE")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
=isnumber(match(sheet2!A23, 'sheet1'!A:A, 0))
```

Comment: Yes there is. [Is there a faster CountIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972016/is-there-a-faster-countif/29983885?s=1|109.4327#29983885)

Comment: Your scientific paper passes the reproducibility test (see my test). Great model thank you for work / link

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!1:1048576,Sheet2!A23)>=1,"TRUE","FALSE")
```

Or

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A23)>=1,"TRUE","FALSE")
```

Conducted my own experiment:

```
Sub newnew()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Range("H1:H4000")

    Dim tmr As String

    tmr = Timer

    For Each Item In rng
        Item.Calculate
    Next Item

    Debug.Print Timer - tmr

End Sub
```

[image]

and yes Jeeped's method is superior :-p :-p :-p