# Running Macro Crashes Excel

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm trying to run a macro but now it keeps freezing excel.
It runs with 10 cells, but when the macro is applied to almost two hundred, it freezes and crashes.

```
Sub eancheck()

    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim Msg As String
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet3")
    Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long
    lr1 = s1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = s2.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 2 To lr1
   s1.Cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        For j = 2 To lr2
            If s2.Range("A" & j) = s1.Range("D" & i) Then
                's1.Range("D" & i) = s2.Range("B" & j)
                s1.Cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I'm having problems with other macros too, and i think is because of the size of the range. How can i fix it?

Note: The macro runs when searching 10 values in a sheet with two columns with almost 200.000 values each, but when instead of 10 is 200, crashes.

Comment: Execute the code one step at the time by pressing F8 when you cross the lines lr1= and lr2= hover over those two variables and see what they hold.

Comment: Dim i As Long, j As Long <- it froze there. since im looking for 200 values in a 200.000 , might that be the problem?

Comment: The obvious thing is what are the values of lr1 and lr2. I doubt you need two loops. Also, why don't you use conditional formatting?

Comment: I thought no-fill on a colorindex scale was -4142.

Comment: @CátiaFonseca You have two loops and for one i value it iterates 200 times for j in this case which is not required.

Comment: @ImranMalek in the future, what do you suggest to avoid this? I'm applying macros to a range of 500 cells and I sure don't want excel to freeze again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional formatting in your sheet1 with formula and apply it on range like D2:D5000 or whatever is suitable.

> =COUNTIF(Sheet3!A2,D2)>0

[image]

Comment: CF makes sense I think, but I think it needs to be `=COUNTIF(Sheet3!A2:A1000,D2)>0` or similar?

Comment: `=isnumber(match(...)) is less calculation cycles. ([...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972016/is-there-a-faster-countif/29983885?s=1|105.6869#29983885))

Comment: Yes ! i will do that ! thank you. one less macro to run !

Comment: @SJR , exactly! worked like a charm. I ran a macro to avoid the user deleting the condition, but I think its the only way to excel not crash.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try Declaring all the required variables separately.
2. Use Application.ScreenUpdating = false in the beginning of the program.
3. Your first line of for loop can be outside the for loop as well.
4. Use Collections to make the checks.

For Example, I started with data like this on Sheet 1 Col A,

[image: Col A on Sheet 1]

And data like this on Sheet 3 Col A.

[image: Col A on Sheet 3]

And this is the Macro that I have,

```
Sub eancheck()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim s1 As Worksheet
    Dim s2 As Worksheet
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim lr1 As Long
    Dim lr2 As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim Sheet1ObjectsCol As Collection
    Dim Sheet3ObjectsCol As Collection
    Dim IdentifierCol As Collection

Set s1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set s2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

Set Sheet1ObjectsCol = New Collection
Set Sheet3ObjectsCol = New Collection
Set IdentifierCol = New Collection

lr1 = s1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = s2.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
s1.Range("D2" & ":" & "D" & lr1).Interior.ColorIndex = 0


'Load the collections
For i = 2 To lr1
Sheet1ObjectsCol.Add s1.Range("A" & i).Value
Next



'Load the collections
 On Error Resume Next
 For i = 2 To lr2
 Sheet3ObjectsCol.Add s2.Range("A" & i).Value, CStr(s2.Range("A" & i).Value)
 Next



'Create the Identifier Collection
For i = 1 To Sheet1ObjectsCol.Count
            ColorValReq = 0
    For j = 1 To Sheet3ObjectsCol.Count
        If Sheet1ObjectsCol(i) = Sheet3ObjectsCol(j) Then
            ColorValReq = 3
            GoTo Idenitified
        End If
    Next

Idenitified:
IdentifierCol.Add ColorValReq
Next

For i = 1 To IdentifierCol.Count
    j = i + 1
    If IdentifierCol(i) = 3 then
      s1.Range("D" & j).Interior.ColorIndex = IdentifierCol(i)
    End if
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

And this is the output I got,

[image: Final Output]

Comment: i Ran into an error in your code. Method Range of object _worksheet failed in s1.Range(D2 & ":" & "D" & lr1).Interior.ColorIndex = 0 
Can u help? maybe i must adjust the range , but it seems right to me.

Comment: My mistake - Try this one - s1.Range("D2" & ":" & "D" & lr1).Interior.ColorIndex = 0 and this should work. can you also tell me the last row of Column A in Sheet1 and Column A in Sheet3 on your workbook.

Comment: you can also load all these objects inside a collection and run it. That will be way faster than this.

Comment: it worked, but it froze again ! my bad. so how do i load into a colection. sorry , i'm not so pro in excel and i'm just trying to make several macros to make somebody's life easier/faster.

Comment: No problem. can you please provide a small sample of data in your colA on sheet 1 and ColA on sheet3 and your expected output. I am more interested to see the expected output.

Comment: no problem. 
Column D as a range of EAN's, each I don't know what is the size of it because the user will paste on there and it may vary. Column A in sheet 2 as the EAN and the Column B the state of it (exists)

Comment: Updated the answer. please check if it helps.

Comment: So i have this column in Sheet 1. And i want to know is these values exist in the second sheet, and if it does i want to highlight them.

Column D - Sheet 1

Column A and B - Sheet 3

Column A and B - Sheet 3

I will try to run your code but i think my problem only can be solved by studying more. Because altho you solved my problem (thank you so much for that), i do have more macros that work in a big range and that may be the cause of the freezing.