# Conditional Formatting 1 column based on 5 columns from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have not found an answer to this anywhere, so here it goes. I have a sheet with Client_ID numbers on it. I also have 20+ other sheets in the same workbook with similar client_ID numbers in them.

I have a "main work sheet" that needs to know if the list of client ID's has ever appeared on any of the other 20+ sheets, and it needs to be highlighted. I have not found an answer that extends to as many sheets as I want it to. Also, if duplicate values also appeared in the "main work sheet" I would also like the values to be highlighted.

Here is a sample data structure. Client ID's 6548, 4568, 32177, 8484, and 6589 would be highlighted.

"main work sheet"

```
client_ID
4568
32177
6548
6549
8484
6589
6589
```

"Sheet 1/20"

```
client_ID
4568
32177
256
3744
8484
```

"Sheet 2/20"

```
client_ID
4168
3687
6548
5852
1584
```

Comment: Is VBA an option?

Comment: VBA is definitely an option. @Zac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the Name of all the sheets to check in another range:

[image]

then do a 3D COUNTIFS():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'" & $G$1:$G$3 & "'!A:A"),A1))>1
```

[image]

Comment: Oh nice, even better!

Comment: I suspect that I've misunderstood the question but doesn't OP wants the ID to be highlighted in individual sheets?

Comment: @Zac not as I read it, but I may be wrong, but it is simple enough to apply the same rule to all the sheets, referring back to the list on the single page.

Comment: Would it be possible to add that to your answer? I only ask because this is way beyond my knowledge base

Comment: @Zac as I believe this answered the question, I will do it in the comment, simply apply `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'" & Sheet1!$G$1:$G$3 & "'!A:A"),A1))>1` to all desired pages.

Comment: Good answer, this did the job perfectly.  I like the pictures as well.  Thank you!

Comment: Perfect, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use OR() and check explicitly named sheets:

`=OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!$A:$A,0)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,Sheet3!$A:$A,0)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,Sheet4!$A:$A,0)))`

Comment: fwiw, MATCH is much more efficient than COUNTIF (see [Is there a faster CountIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972016/is-there-a-faster-countif/29983885#29983885)). For 20-odd worksheets, I'd recommend ISNUMBER(MATCH(...)) over COUNTIF.

Comment: Match would return errors for values that are not found though.

Comment: @ValonMiller that is why he wrapped it in `ISNUMBER` which would return FALSE for errors

Comment: ISNUMBER(MATCH(...)) would return true for match and false for no match. For all intents and purposes, all you want is true/false anyways.

Comment: ah, that makes sense then.