# Find duplicates in large dataset Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba, large-data

I have this task that seems to be recurring and I would need a better solution for.

I pull data from two different databases in two different systems (don't ask why, it's just the way it is). When I do this, preferably I would like the two datasets to be the same size. I have a primary key on both, let's calll this "ID". What I want to do is check this ID from table1 and table2 and get the unique values (so I can go on and see why I have more in one table). My dataset gets very large (roughly a bit over 100 000 rows) which makes my VLOOKUP function in excel work extremely slow. Is there any way of solving this in excel with **speed**? Solutions using VBA macro, pivottables or excels built-in SQL would do fine. Using excel 2016.

Sample table:

```
ID_TableA           ID_TableB
123456789208435989  123456789208435989
123456789239344137  123456789368934745
123456789368934745  123456789381895013
123456789381895013  123456789447760867
123456789447760867  123456789466692531
123456789466692531  123456789470807304
123456789470807304  123456789504343451
123456789504343451  123456789571573964
123456789563853210  123456789666106771
123456789571573964  123456789683792216
123456789666106771  123456789719645070
123456789683792216  123456789747751420
123456789719645070  123456789770236822
123456789747751420  123456789839975896
123456789770236822  123456789920037815
123456789825288494  123456789930612286
123456789839975896  123456789936072949
123456789920037815  123456789948401617
123456789930612286  123456789982601470
123456789936072949  
123456789948401617  
123456789982601470
```

The result from the solution should output:

```
123456789825288494
123456789563853210
123456789239344137
```

The data in the tables are 18 char long numberseries where the first 9 numbers are not changing.

**Edit:** Both of the two tables could contain unique values. The result should return values that are unique from both tables.

Comment: You've tagged with SQL, and in fact SQL would be a much better tool for this problem than Excel.  Do you have these two tables loaded into a single database?  If not, can you do that?

Comment: A **warning** to anyone planning to expand the sample data beyond 1K rows; the sample data is **not** representative of the narrative and contains a majority of unique entries.

Comment: Perhaps you can [Edit] your question to make it clear that you want to return unique values from EITHER table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have both these columns in separate tables on a single database, then this problem is easy to handle using SQL.  Here is one way:

```
SELECT a.ID_TableA
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
    ON a.ID_TableA = b.ID_TableB
WHERE b.ID_TableB IS NULL
UNION
SELECT b.ID_TableB
FROM TableA a
RIGHT JOIN TableB b
    ON a.ID_TableA = b.ID_TableB
WHERE a.ID_TableB IS NULL;
```

Another way, using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT ID_TableA
FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB b WHERE a.ID_TableA = b.ID_TableB)
UNION
SELECT ID_TableB
FROM TableA b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableA a WHERE a.ID_TableA = b.ID_TableB);
```

Comment: Would this return Unique values from both tables ?

Comment: @Flyckten I did not know you had this requirement.  I have updated my answer to handle this possibility.

Comment: Yeah, wasn't clear in the question since I just realised that might be the case. Thanks for your answer, this will do!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [powerquery](/questions/tagged/powerquery) (`Get & Transform Data`):

```
let
    SourceA = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblA"]}[Content],
    SourceB = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblB"]}[Content],
    UniqueA = Table.Join(SourceA,{"ID_TableA"},SourceB,{"ID_TableB"},JoinKind.LeftAnti),
    UniqueB = Table.Join(SourceA,{"ID_TableA"},SourceB,{"ID_TableB"},JoinKind.RightAnti),
    OutputList = List.Combine({UniqueA[ID_TableA], UniqueB[ID_TableB]})
in
    OutputList
```

*(Edited having seen your requirement to return unique values from EITHER table)*

Doing some testing, using some mocked up data in a similar format, this seems pretty fast:

> ```
> Input from tblA     Rows: 250,000
> Input from tblB     Rows: 250,000
>
> Start:        25/10/2018 14:17:13 
> End:          25/10/2018 14:17:15
>
> Returned 41,042 unique values in about 2 seconds
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this! Follow up question, being a bit new to power query, how could I make the output into a table with two columns, one containing Unique IDs from SourceA and one containg Unique IDs from SourceB?

Used the following code (in addition to yours), but I end up with a out put of two "Lists" in just two cells of the table:
    Output = #table(
        {"UniqueInA","UniqueInB"},
        {
            {UniqueA[ID_TableA],UniqueB[ID_TableB]}
        })

Comment: Figured it out using the function Table.FromColumns! Thanks for your previous help.

Answer (score 2):

While I would do that with an Access query, as others suggested, here's my 2 cents for your question.

`VLOOKUP` IS slow and not the right function for this.
`Countif` is a bit better, but `ISNUMBER(MATCH())` seems to be the fastest combination by far.
Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29983885/78522